# Can a system be engineered to cause a standing wave resonance with gravitational waves

Tags: gravity, waves, spacetime, reflection, gravitational-waves

Can a system be engineered to cause a standing wave resonance with gravitational waves?

It appears that gravity waves can be reflected. 
Do Mirrors for Gravitational Waves Exist?
Stephen J. Minter, Kirk Wegter-McNelly, Raymond Y. Chiao
https://arxiv.org/abs/0903.0661

Could someone engineer a system, using those mirrors?

Comment: By can do you mean is it possible theoretically, practically, or logistically?

Comment: @PaulChilds Out of curiosity, what's the difference between"practically" and "logistically" in this context?

Comment: Both theoretically, and practically, using ambient gravity waves from black hole collisions.

Comment: Do you have some target figure in mind for a cavity quality factor? E.g. that someone could build a GWaser?

Comment: Would the quality factor need to be on the lower end, so it will work with a wider range of frequencies?

Comment: Even if we could build a such system, how can we measure the gravitational waves inside it?

Comment: Could the waves be measured with a laser interferometer?

Comment: @PaulChilds, I like your new word "GWaser".  That's very clever.  On another note, there is no known gravity reflector, so there is no known way to obtain standing gravity waves.

Comment: Would the theoretical gravity reflector mentioned above work?

Comment: https://arxiv.org/pdf/0903.0661.pdf

Answer (score 1):

> Can a system be engineered to cause a standing wave resonance with
>   gravitational waves?

This is precisely how the [first attempt to measure gravity waves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weber_bar) worked. It consisted of a large metal cylinder, cooled to remove thermal noise. If a gravity wave passed it would being to resonate, which would be detected via piezo sensors.

Unfortunately the S/N ratio was far below what we now know to be required.

Comment: Is there a way to amplify the signal, using some sort of pumping process, or through reflection?

Comment: It did so through reflection, in essence, but in the same fashion that a guitar string does when the wave hits the frets. This is basically what a standing wave is, the amplification of a single wave by reflecting it back on itself in a particular way. Note that most radio antennas also work in this fashion.